Meaning of "on our hands" in the sentence "we have a family mutiny on our hands"
On Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary, I found the following example sentence:

We have a family mutiny on our hands!

However, the phrase "on our hands" could either mean:

That family mutiny is at at our disposal. Or
It's our responsibility to blame for family mutiny.

And for me both are okay.
So, which meaning best matches the example or is it ambiguous and either are fine?

Did you find these definitions somewhere? Please tell where so we can talk about the source; the first seems wrong.

@AndyBonner, the definitions are at the entry for the phrase "on one's hands", you can use Google Dictionary to find too. And the example in the question is at the entry for "munity".

What I find in the Google auto-generated results for "define on one's hands" is: "used to indicate that someone is responsible for dealing with someone or something"; that's like my answer: responsibility to deal is different than blame.

@AndyBonner, just FYI, as I already accepted your answer, it shows me two meanings, one as you mentioned the other is, at someone's disposal. Example:
"since I retired I've had more time on my hands".

It's true that "on our hands" can be about responsibility for blame, like having "blood on your hands," usually as a reference to the mention that Pontius Pilate washed his hands after sentencing Jesus (and the tradition that he then went mad and obsessively continued washing his hands like Lady Macbeth).
But it can often speak not just of blame, but of responsibility to take care of something. "The babysitter has three toddlers on his hands": He's not to blame for them, but they're his to take care of. The meaning here is "We have a family mutiny [and have to deal with it]."
By the way, I'm not aware of a meaning of "on one's hands" that means "at one's disposal." You might be thinking of the phrase "at hand."

It's not "responsibility BLAME" like "blood on your hands". It's responsibility = DUTY (to do something)

@FumbleFingers Right; I was addressing and then dismissing the OP's guess. Maybe I should make that clearer...

It is never a welcome thing to have something 'on one's hands'; it is an unwanted and, often, unplanned responsibility.

@MichaelHarvey Unless one finds oneself with a lot of time on one's hands!

@stangdon: But there are quite a few instances of "time weighs heavily on our hands" (we're bored, frustrated with nothing to do). I just checked, and there don't seem to be any accessible instances of anything except "time" weighing heavily.

@FumbleFingers I suppose what's really surprising there is that it's our hands that time weighs on. Plenty of things "weigh on [someone]," without specifying where, and sometimes "weigh heavy on [their] shoulders." The burdens of state are apparently concentrated on the head. But no, I can't think of any other abstractions that are handled by hand!

What if you were the hiring manager for a ranch?

@AndyBonner: Well, there's the antonym of "handling a problem", which is to sit on your hands - to refuse to engage, as opposed to having nothing to engage with when you're bored / idle.
